# Can any one suggest a step by step example for using moQ framework

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, moq

Can any one suggest a step by step example for using moQ framework.

any guidelines or thumbrules that has to be followed while mocking objetcs . can be much help.

thanks.

Comment: What are you looking for as an end-goal of going through the example ? Do you have a 'working knowledge' of mock frameworks ?

Comment: Yes . but In most of the examples i saw interface refernce being passed as the argument for Mock constructor(i.e., new Mock<Ifoo>(). can u give an example taking Class as argument.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here's the moq quick-start](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

**Update:** To address your comment...  A large part of writing testable code involves removing dependencies on classes/resources outside the scope of your control.  A very common approach to doing this is by talking to interfaces instead of concrete examples.

It's a little much to describe properly (especially since I just rolled out of bed), so let suggest you pick up a copy of Roy Osherove's 'The Art of Unit Testing'.  It's a fairly short book and is filled with good advice and lots of summary information to get you familiar with many of the approaches to unit testing.

Comment: In the test case i'm trying to call a method (Which is implemented and programmed to throw an exception) using interface instance. But the test still passes . what does the Setup method acctually do here .(below is the sample code).
[Test]
 public void Empty()
        {
             IQueue Qref;
        Mock<IQueue> MockObj= new Mock<IQueue>();
            MockObj.Setup(x => x.IsEmpty).Returns(true);           
            Assert.IsTrue(MockObj.Object.IsEmpty);
            
        }

Comment: I think that would best be asked in a new question, I'm only a somewhat familiar with moq and putting it in a new question will get developers more familiar with the framework to look at it.

Answer (score 4):

I only started to use Moq recently and I am not sure how much help this will be but if you can get your hands on Chapter 3 of [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430210079) there is a really good step-by-step example of using moq and NUnit with ASP.NET MVC.